# How to pass list of function and all its arguments to be executed in another function in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of functions and its arguments like this:

```
(func1, *arg1), (func2, *arg2),...
```

I want to pass them into another function to execute them like this:

```
for func, arg* in (list of funcs, args):
   func(arg*)
```

How to do it in python? I have tried several but it doesn't like unpacking and *arg at the same time.

Comment: Apart from `arg*` being invalid syntax in Python, what exact problem are you having? "It doesn't like" is a bit vague. Also please show the exact format of the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [*-operator to unpack the arguments out of the tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

For example, suppose the format of items in your invocation list is `(function,arg1,arg2,...)`. In other words, `item[0]` is your function, while `item[1:]` are the arguments the should be given to the function.

```
def f1(x1):
    print("f1 {0}".format(x1))

def f2(x1,x2):
    print("f2 {0} {1}".format(x1,x2))

for data in ((f1,5),(f2,3,4)):
    data[0](*data[1:])
# output:
#   f1 5
#   f2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just use list of tuple where first is the function name, and rest are arguments.

```
def a(*args,**kwargs):
    print 1

list_f = [(a,1,2,3)]

for f in list_f:
    f[0](f[1:])
```

Comment: Your solution call the functions with one argument - a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function and arguments are separate in the tuple,

```
def squarer(*args):
    return map(lambda x: x*2, args)

def subtracter(*args):
    return map(lambda x: x-1, args)

funcAndArgs = [(squarer, [1,2,3,4]), (subtracter, [1,2,3,4])]

for func, args in funcAndArgs:
    print func(*args)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```